# Altering JSON response in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rendering, response

I have a model named **User** and in many actions i am rendering the response as json. for ex while showing the user data, i am using

`@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
render json: {data: @user}`

Now i have a requirement that while responding user data i need to show only last 2 digit of the mobile number for ex) ********78, is there any way to achieve this, Because altering the response in each action will be too difficult so is there any way to write a common method for handling this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method in `user` model

`user.rb`

```
def as_json(options = {})
  # use options as per need
  {id: self.id, name: self.name, mobile: mask}
end

def mask
  # masking logic
end
```

You can write a method which masks the initial characters and do `render json: {data: @user.as_json)}`

Checkout [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) link

Comment: i have executed what u have said but in a different way `render json: {data: @user.as_json(only: [:id, :email]), methods: :mask}`, but i having response `{ "id": 121, "email":"test@test.com", "mask": "********45"}` ie the name of the method is the key of the mobile number. Can please find out what is the problem.

Comment: You can name the method whatever you want in json response

Comment: Thats where the problem is i need the response to be mobile number but for the masking logic `"********" + self.mobile_number.slice(8,9)`, if the method name is mobile_number it will cause a infinite loop.

Comment: yes it is working right now. Thanks for your help.., but i have another issue, i have some columns to be excluded and some to be included it differs on different action, but if if am overriding the as_json like this i will not able to do so., is there any other alternatives.

Comment: Now i have solved it by using `render json: {data: @user.as_json(only: [:id, :email]).merge(mobile_number: @user.mask)}` but there is a another problem there are certain actions in which i need to show a list of user, this solution won't suit there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem by

```
def as_json(options = {})
  users = super
  users['mobile_number'] = "********" + users['mobile_number'].slice(8,9).last if users['mobile_number'].present?
  users
end
```

when i call

```
 render json: {data: @user.as_json}
```

even if @user can contain collection of record, the mobile number for each record will be rendered in the format ********78.

the response now will be

```
{
    “id”: 143,
    “email”:test1@test.com,
    “mobile_number”: “********67”
}
```

And thanks for [benchwarmer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087546/benchwarmer) help.